# fullcalendar dayClick function not working from ajax call json data

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I can get the dayClick function to work when the data is included in the $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ header : {} etc.... }) but the dayClick function will not work from an ajax returned data $('#calendar').fullCalendar(JSON.parse(data)) even though the data is near identical to the typed in data.

I get a javascript error:
 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'

I am making an ajax call:

```
        $.post('/Home/CalendarEntries', { TenantID: 2 }, function (data) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar(JSON.parse(data)); 
            }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("Result: " + o.script + " " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)         });
```

I'm posting back data from the controller...

```
        CalendarEvents ce = new CalendarEvents();
        ce.sJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cEntries, Formatting.None);

        return View(ce);
```

where

```
public class CalendarEvents
{
    public string sJSON { get; set; }
}
```

This works well for all data and shows up well on the calendar. I click on a date and I get the javascript error above with nothing happening.

this example works and functions well for the dayClick event.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
            },
            defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            businessHours: true, // display business hours
            editable: true,
            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) { $(this).css('background-color', 'red'); },
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Business Lunch',
                    start: '2018-03-03T13:00:00',
                    constraint: 'businessHours'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2018-03-13T11:00:00',
                    constraint: 'availableForMeeting', // defined below
                    color: '#257e4a'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2018-03-18',
                    end: '2018-03-20'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Party',
                    start: '2018-03-29T20:00:00'
                },
                // areas where "Meeting" must be dropped
                {
                    id: 'availableForMeeting',
                    start: '2018-03-11T10:00:00',
                    end: '2018-03-11T16:00:00',
                    rendering: 'background'
                },
                {
                    id: 'availableForMeeting',
                    start: '2018-03-13T10:00:00',
                    end: '2018-03-13T16:00:00',
                    rendering: 'background'
                },

                // red areas where no events can be dropped
                {
                    start: '2018-03-24',
                    end: '2018-03-28',
                    overlap: false,
                    rendering: 'background',
                    color: '#ff9f89'
                },
                {
                    start: '2018-03-06',
                    end: '2018-03-08',
                    overlap: false,
                    rendering: 'background',
                    color: '#ff9f89'
                }
            ]
        });
```

I have recreated this data in the controller and passed it back through the ajax call and the text data is near identical except that everything is in double quotes from the            ce.sJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cEntries, Formatting.None);

All the data on the calendar is identical to the example above from the passed back ajax call but a click on any day will produce the javascript error above.

If I change the above typed in data example for the dayClick to: 
                dayClick: "function (date, jsEvent, view) { $(this).css('background-color', 'red'); }",

notice the double quotes at the beginning of function and the end of the function. I will get the same javascript apply error above as the passed back ajax call data.

In the controller, I have removed the double quotes for the dayClick value in the serialized text before posing back and have the data passed back for the dayClick value identical to the typed in data example dayClick value and the JSON.parse(data) fails with a javascript error.

What am I doing wrong with the JSON data?

Comment: Are you trying to pass all the calendar setup options in from JSON (as opposed to just the events data)? JSON doesn't support defining functions within it. It's a data interchange format, not a programming language. But why are you trying to do this anyway? I can't think what the use case would be. Just set the calendar options in the JavaScript code like normal. JSON would be useful for loading event data from the server, not for setting callbacks

Comment: I am using this to show different people their own personalized calendars. I only started sending the dayclick event in JSON when someone mentioned that they wanted their own separate event to happen when they clicked on certain dates. Those dates would be specific to them. I thought it easiest to send the function along with the events and then ran into this problem. How else can I make a personalized event specifically for one or maybe two people when I set the options for everyone else? Or is that not possible?

Comment: You could inject the settings into your page using server side code, potentially